# Reading a handlebar template file in a jest test

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, jestjs

So my app uses webpack to pack stuff up including the handlebars we use.

Our Jest tests are not included in webpack. I wish i could import the handlebars templates somehow, but i cant figure out how could i read the .hbs file ?

In my app, i use handlebar-loader so i can just `require('path/file.hbs')` but handlebars templates can`t be processd by jest.

So, in jest i'm using only the `handlebars.js` instead of the `handlebars-loader`

`const handlebars = require('handlebars');`

I've tryed to read the templates with `XMLHttpRequest` but thats a browser object.

```
const handlebars = require('handlebars');

// this function wont work...
const readHandlebarTemplate = file =>
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

const tableTemplate = handlebars.compile(readHandlebarTemplate('./templates/html-table.hbs'));
const embedTableTemplate =  handlebars.compile(readHandlebarTemplate('./templates/embedded-table.hbs'));
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?